# How to call a Dart program from Javascript?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Given that Dart will need to inter-operate with other javascript frameworks.  In the client-web environment what are the current or intended best-practices to communicate with a Dart program from javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you need to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate with Dart however a interorp layer is planned and should arrive in dart2js any day now (although I believe that its initial incarnation will focus more **Dart->JavaScript** than **JavaScript->Dart**).

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

js.context.jQuery();
var context = js.context;  
var param = js.map({ 'modal': true, "width":1000, "height":600});
js.context.jQuery("#dialog").dialog(param);
```

in html

```html
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

The above code open a div as dialog using jQuery.